# Delphi - threads and FindFirst function

Tags: delphi, search, file, multithreading

I'm encountering a big problem when i'm trying to make a recursive search function inside a thread (using delphi 7) bellow is the code:

```
TParcFicDir = class(TThread)
private
 several variables..
 protected
    procedure Execute; override;
  public
    constructor Create(CreateSuspended: Boolean);


constructor TParcFicDir.Create(CreateSuspended: Boolean);
begin
 inherited Create(CreateSuspended);
end;

procedure TParcFicDir.Execute;
begin
 try
  FindFiles(FStartDir,FMask);//'c:\' and '*.*'
 except on e:Exception do
 end;
end;

procedure TParcFicDir.FindFiles(StartDir, FileMask: string);
var
  wTmp              : string;
  f:TextFile;
  wTempSR:TSearchRec;

  function Search(StartDir, FileMask: string): string;
  var
    SR              : TSearchRec;
    IsFound         : Boolean;
    files           : integer;
    dirs            : integer;
    t               : string;
  begin
    try
      files := 0;
      dirs := 0;
      if StartDir[length(StartDir)] <> '\' then
        StartDir := StartDir + '\';
      try
        IsFound := (FindFirst(StartDir + '*.*', faAnyFile, SR) = 0);// here the thread gets interrupted
      except on e: Exception do
      end;
      while IsFound do
      begin
        if (SR.Name <> '.') and (SR.Name <> '..') then
          if ((SR.Attr and faDirectory) <> 0) then
          if FScanDirs then 
          begin
            inc(dirs);
            t := Search(StartDir + SR.Name, FileMask);
            try
              files := files + strtoint(copy((t), 0, pos('#', t) - 1));//old code, don't take on calcul;
              Delete(t, 1, pos('#', t));
              dirs := dirs + strtoint(t);
            except on e: Exception do
            end;
            begin
              t := StartDir + SR.Name;
              wTmp := t;
              wtmp := '';
              Inc(FDirNo);
              writeln(f,t);
              inc(filno);
            end;
          end
          else
          if ScanFiles then 
          begin
           inc(filno);
           inc(files);
          end;
        IsFound := FindNext(SR) = 0;
      end;
      Result := IntToStr(files) + '#' + IntToStr(dirs);
      sysutils.FindClose(SR);
    except on e: Exception do
    end;
  end;
begin
 filno := 0;
  try
    try
      if trim(FPathFileTmp)<>'' then
       AssignFile(f, FPathFileTmp+'Temp.bak')
      else
       AssignFile(f,ExtractFileDir(GetDllName)+'\Temp.bak');
      Rewrite(f);
      Search(StartDir, FileMask);
      if StartDir[length(StartDir)] = '\' then
        delete(StartDir, length(StartDir), 1);
      wTmp := StartDir;
      wTmp := '';
      if FindFirst(StartDir, faDirectory, wTempSR) = 0 then
      writeln(f);
      writeln(f);
      CloseFile(f);
    except on e: Exception do
    end;
  finally
  end;
end;
```

ok, probably the code is a little messed up, but i don't understand why the thread ends at 'findfirst' part....i googled it, no results.

any help will be appreciated!

Thanks in advance

Comment: Add an ShowMessage(E.Message) in your exception handlers, when an exception is raised, at least you have some information about it.

Comment: Yeah.  `try..except on Exception do end;` is a very bad idea.

Comment: Are threads actually relevant to this question at all? What if you run this code in a program all by itself? You say the code is messed up, so worry about that first, and *then* worry about making it work in a separate thread.

Comment: Well I guess you forgot to tell us WHAT is wrong with that? Sorry, but we don't mind compiling and trying to figure out what the problem IS.

Comment: I agree with Migajek.. If you want us to help you, the least you could do is explain what the problem is.

Comment: 1) i tried with try..except..showmessage - doesn't show anything
2) rob, migajek & all - i said is 'messed up'- that isn't arranged,indented, etc, NOT THAT ISN'T FUNCTIONAL. code is working in a program by itself. and i believe it's related to threads, because the code is inside a thread no?

my problem is - function findfirst doesn't work inside the thread. 
 
so,please instead of giving not relevant answers, can someone have an idea on this and help me? i searched a lot, but it seems that nobody had this issue.

thanks in advance!

Comment: If the code is "messed up" because it doesn't look nice, then take 2 minutes and *make it look nice*. Remove as many barriers as possible preventing people from helping you. Ugly code is a distracting barrier. So are irrelevant details. One possibly irrelevant detail is that this is in a separate thread. You don't have to *wonder* whether it's thread-related. Test it in your main thread and find out. Even better, run it in a new program that runs nothing but this code. When you say something "doesn't work," you must be more specific. Don't make people guess; that's another barrier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your posted code I see that you [try catch and forget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2349378/new-programming-jargon-you-coined/2457432#2457432) the exception.   When you have broken code that contains something like that, the very first thing I do is remove the empty except block.   Odds are that don't know what is going on because your throwing the information you need away.

You have two calls to `FindFirst()` in your code.   The usage of the one where your trying to find a directory is suspect.   I would change your code to something like this.

```
var
 SR : TSearchRec;

begin
  if FindFirst('C:\',faDirectory,SR) <> 0 then
     RaiseLastOSError;
end;
```

Then you will see the reason `FindFirst()` Failed.

Instead of using `FindFirst()` in the case where your looking for the directory I would use the `DirectoryExists()` call instead.